# How can I prevent a class called Index masking the package in scaladoc?

Tags: scala, scaladoc

I have a class called `Index`, representing a secondary index within DynamoDB. When I generate scaladoc for it, it overwrites the documentation of it's parent package, as that's called `index.html` as is the class's documentation.

Is there any way to avoid this behaviour, other than renaming the class?